# expandablelistview c добавлением Group/Child

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Нужно сделать контролл следующего вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это осуществить?
На ум приходит только использовать expandablelistview, добавить в конец каждого списка Child еще один элемент, на который повесить функцию добавления нового Child, но мне кажется, это какой-то неправильный путь.

Comment: Скорей всего это обычной footter для child-a. У ExpandableListView есть такой метод addChildFooterView(). Думаю копать сюда